# upgrade component from option api to composition api (this.$parent)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this component "Tab" that works in vue 3 (using option api)

```
export default {
    name: "Tab",
    props: {
        name: {required: true},
        iconClass: {required: true},
        selected: {default: false}
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isActive: false
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.isActive = this.selected;
    },
    created() {
        this.$parent.tabs.push(this);
    },
}
```

but I want to convert it using composition api:

```
import {onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref} from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Tab",
    props: {
        name: {required: true},
        iconClass: {required: true},
        selected: {default: false}
    },
    setup(props, {parent}) {
        const isActive = ref(false)

        onBeforeMount(() => {
            parent.tabs.push(this);
        })

        onMounted(() => {
            isActive.value = props.selected;
        })

        return {isActive}
    }
}
```

A vue warning is shown in console:

```
Unhandled error during execution of beforeMount hook
```

and it seems to be from here:

```
 parent.tabs.push(this);
```

Any ideas?

*** **UPDATE** ***

The tabs component (parent):

```
name: "Tabs",
    setup() {
        const tabs = ref([])

        const selectedTab = (selectedTab) => {
            tabs.value.forEach(tab => {
                tab.isActive = (tab.name === selectedTab.name);
            })
        }

        return {tabs, selectedTab}
    }
```

*** **UPDATE 2** ***

I have tried with provide/inject .... but is seems not to work (the tabs apears but is not changing the content when selecting another tab)

Here is the "Tabs" - parent

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill flex-column flex-md-row">
                <li class="nav-item" v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab">
                    <a class="nav-link mb-sm-3 mb-md-0" @click="selectedTab(tab)" :class="{'active' : tab.isActive}" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="ni mr-2" :class="[tab.iconClass]"></i>{{ tab.name }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {provide, ref} from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Tabs",
    setup() {
        const tabs = ref([])

        const selectedTab = (selectedTab) => {
            tabs.value.forEach(tab => {
                tab.isActive = (tab.name === selectedTab.name);
            })
        }

        provide('tabs', tabs.value)

        return {tabs, selectedTab}
    }    
}
</script>
```

and the "Tab" component:

```
<template>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show" :class="{'active' : isActive}">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {onBeforeMount, inject, onMounted, ref} from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Tab",
    props: {
        name: {required: true},
        iconClass: {required: true},
        selected: {default: false}
    },
    setup(props) {
        const isActive = ref(false)

        onBeforeMount(() => {
            const tabs = inject("tabs")
            tabs.push({
                name: props.name,
                iconClass: props.iconClass,
                selected: props.selected,
            })
        })

        onMounted(() => {
            isActive.value = props.selected;
        })

        return {isActive}
    }    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent from the instance using the [`getCurrentInstance()` method](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance)

Then to access `data` you could use `instance.parent.data`, but that won't work, because your data is not defined there. Vue makes the data passed to the view available still through `instance.parent.proxy`, so you can access the Proxia via `instance.parent.proxy.tabs`

And while his *should work* accessing data of the parent this way is highly discouraged. You may want to consider passing props directly (if it's a parent-child relationship), or you could use the `provide/inject` way of doing it, or if the parent is used only once, then a global store may work as-well. Doing it using `parent.proxy.*` relies on internals that may cause a braking change at some point.

Example also includes passing with `provide/inject`

```js
var app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {

    const tabs = Vue.ref([1])
    Vue.provide('tabs', tabs)

    const selectedTab = (selectedTab) => {
      tabs.value.forEach(tab => {
        tab.isActive = (tab.name === selectedTab.name);
      })
    }

    return {
      tabs,
      selectedTab
    }
  }
});

app.component("child-component", {
  template: `<div ><button @click="gift"></button></div>`,
  setup() {
    const instance = Vue.getCurrentInstance();
    const tabs = Vue.inject('tabs')
    const gift = ()=>{
      instance.parent.proxy.tabs.push(''); // using proxy
      tabs.value.push(''); // using inject
    }
    Vue.onBeforeMount(() => {
      gift();
    })

    return {gift}
  }
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.6/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
‍
  {{tabs}}
  <child-component></child-component>
  <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

Comment: thx! But now I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, any idea ?

Comment: That means it `tabs` is undefined in parent. See note about using `$parent` to access data [v2](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance ) [v3](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#parent)   _Use `$parent` and `$children` sparingly - they mostly serve as an escape-hatch. Prefer using props and events for parent-child communication._

Comment: tabs is defined - i have updated the question

Comment: I have tried with provide and inject but is not working (I am missing something). In the parent component (tabs) `provide('tabs', tabs.value)` and in the child component (tab) onBeforeMount : `const tabs = inject("tabs")  tabs.push({name: props.name, iconClass: props.iconClass, selected: props.selected })`

Comment: I'm guessing you were missing `tabs.value.push` since tabs is a `ref` and not a `reactive`

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code of the components. Using `tabs.value.push` I get an error: `TypeError: tabs.push.push is not a function`

Comment: have a look at the example code `provide('tabs', tabs.value)` should be `provide('tabs', tabs)` and `tabs.push` should be `tabs.value.push`. The value of the `ref` changes changes, so if you're passing the `value` it will not update the ref.

Comment: I get it. But still not display the content of the selected tab. It shows the content of the first tab.

Comment: I still not make it work. I reproduce the example here https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-worker-4tjl8